# gunicorn.service: Failed to determine user credentials: No such process

Tags: linux, deployment, django

I keep getting an error when trying to set gunicorn with my django project

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-02-04 17:45:34 +01; 25min ago
TriggeredBy: ● gunicorn.socket
   Main PID: 754981 (code=exited, status=217/USER)

Feb 04 17:45:34 vps141106 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Feb 04 17:45:34 vps141106 systemd[754981]: gunicorn.service: Failed to determine user credentials: No such process
Feb 04 17:45:34 vps141106 systemd[754981]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step USER spawning /home/root/venv/bin/gunicorn: No such process
Feb 04 17:45:34 vps141106 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Feb 04 17:45:34 vps141106 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 04 17:45:34 vps141106 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 04 17:45:34 vps141106 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 04 17:45:34 vps141106 systemd[1]: Failed to start gunicorn daemon.
```

This is my service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/root/test
ExecStart=/home/root/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          test.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Im getting those errors

```
gunicorn.service: Failed to determine user credentials: No such process
gunicorn.service: Failed at step USER spawning /home/root/venv/bin/gunicorn: No such process
```

Now Im pretty sure I have something in /home/root/venv/bin/gunicorn I just did a

nano /home/root/venv/bin/gunicorn and got this

```
  GNU nano 4.8                                           /home/root/venv/bin/gunicorn                                                     
#!/home/root/venv/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(run())
```

so I have gunicorn installed

now with the first error, Im not sure what is causing it, the system user is called root and has sudo privileges

I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Do you really want to run gunicorn as root?

Comment: shouldn't I? Im new in deployment projects I just want to make sure I don't get permission issues down the line. If I decided to create another user do I need any special permissions to deploy the project without issues?

Comment: No, you very much shouldn't. I don't agree with the logic at all – after all when you're writing Python code, you generally don't just put `except: pass` around everything to make sure "exceptions don't get thrown"; you treat each exception as an indication of a problem to fix. // However, in any case, systemd doesn't actually forbid User=root, so that's not the reason for the error message – it's usually caused by something else. Maybe your distro does not have a group called "www-data"?